# Igx Button to open a link and download a file

Tags: angular, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

Is it possible to download a file (e.g. Power point presentation) through a link when an igx Button is clicked? I could not find any related topic to my question.

Here is my example code:

```
  <button igxButton="raised" (click)="downloadFile()" class="downloadBtn">
    Download File
  </button>
```

and the function:

```
downloadFile() {
   let exampleLink = "https://downloadexamplefile.com/fileid123"
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not specific to the igxButton. The button may be a tirgger for the download action, although the actual action is something that you will need to handle.

An example would be creating a **Service** and specifying the **responseType** option  that upon GET request can return **a blob** representing the downloaded file. Then you can call this service, subscribe to the corresponding observable, and eventually save the file upon **igxButton click**

Example:
https://www.thecodehubs.com/download-file-with-httpclient-in-angular/

Comment: Yes, thank you, I fixed it. I opened the URL with the file for download through window.open(https://www.downloadURL.com");